# Angular JS Error - timepicker.js injector:modulerr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-injector

This is my first AngularJS application so I am a nooby and keep trying to figure things out. But I am receiving an error in my chrome console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]      
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=klikdaily-merchant
&…2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fnode_modules%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A439%3A21)
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1829
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:31768
q    @ angular.js:4681
g    @ angular.js:31768
cb   @ angular.js:31768
c    @ angular.js:31768B
c    @ angular.js:31768f
e    @ angular.js:31768
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:31768
b    @ angular.js:31768
Sf   @ angular.js:31768
d    @ angular.js:31768
```

Everything was fine after i insert module 'angular.circular.timepicker.js' and that error came.

Any thoughts? Thanks before

My Module List

```
angular.module('klikdaily-merchant',['ngMaterial','angular.circular.timepicker'
,'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate', 'vAccordion' , 'material.svgAssetsCache','ngRoute',
'jkAngularCarousel','ngCookies','ngMdIcons'])
```

My Script List

```
<script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-material-icons/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-lib/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-lib/v-accordion.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-circular-timepicker/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-circular-timepicker/dist/javascript/angular.circular.timepicker.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/jk-carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.smooch.io/smooch.min.js"></script>
```

I pick timepicker.js from

http://angularscript.com/angularjs-circular-date-time-picker/

Comment: Can you get the actual error page URL without the `...` truncation? If you click it, it should take you to the actual page

Comment: Never mind. The Circular Time Picker module name is `angular.circular.timepicker`, not `angular.circular.timepicker.js`

Comment: @Phil , Thanks for answer my Question. I already did that and restart my server but the error still same. Another suggestion maybe?

Comment: Refer to my first comment then. Also, update your question code to reflect reality

Answer (score 1):

Please try to inject the dependency like this -'angular.circular.timepicker' without 'js' extension.

```js
angular.module('klikdaily-merchant',['ngMaterial','angular.circular.timepicker'
,'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate', 'vAccordion' , 'material.svgAssetsCache','ngRoute',
'jkAngularCarousel','ngCookies','ngMdIcons'])
```

Comment: Thanks for answer my Question @user6801750. I already did that and restart my server but the error still same. Another suggestion maybe?

Comment: If possible please post entire code here or Plunker link as that will help to troubleshoot.